# NGiNX location block redirect to query string

Tags: nginx, query-string, varnish, nginx-config, varnish-vcl

I'm looking at redirecting my base domain / to a query string, rather than having this done by the end user, but unfortunately, NGiNX location block doesn't play nice with redirect/rewrite and query strings.

I have done the following which seems to work:

```
    map $request_uri $redirect {
        default     0;
        ~*^/$ /?siteId=value;
    }

    location / {
         set $component "backend";
         if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS)$) { return 444; }
         if ($redirect) {return 301 $redirect; }
         include inject_headers.include;
         proxy_pass $backend;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_pass_request_body on; 
         proxy_set_header X-Request-ID $request_id;
         proxy_set_header X-B3-TraceId $request_id;
         proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;
         proxy_hide_header Server;
```

but when this is proxy_passed on, it hits a varnish server which I cannot see it intercepting, but I'm receiving a 404 as it cannot find `example.com/?siteId=value`

Does anyone have any advice/help/done this before and can shine some light on this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you are trying to achieve - e.g. provide example input with the desired output, or something like that ?

Comment: Of course - When a user browsers to `example.com` I'd like this to 301 redirect to `example.com/?siteId=value`

Comment: You can try `if ($arg_siteId == "") { return 301 $scheme$host/?siteId=value; }`

Comment: Would I still need the map for this to work? I've tested on my localhost and I get this `http://localhost/httplocalhost/?siteId=value` Thanks

Comment: Okay, my mistake - `return 301 $scheme://$host/?siteId=value;` I do not think you will need the map.